# Prevent document from losing key bind when a child iframe takes focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Basically my goal is to try to create a keyboard controller for my entire web project and I would like to be able to retain the keybinds I created on the parent document and have them be inherited by the child iframes. Is this possible?

Here is an example setup of what I have right now: http://jsfiddle.net/sahil_signal/d39Nn/9/

```
<div id="tabcontainer">
    <button id="tab1button" type="button">Tab1</button>
    <button id="tab2button" type="button">Tab2</button>
</div>
<iframe id="iframe1container"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe2container"></iframe>

$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
    var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keycode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Tab");
    }
});
```

I want to be able to have the tab key still bound even when the iframe takes focus and I realize I can rebind the tab key to the iframe document, but is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your iframes, you can add an event handler that would trigger top's events...
Placing this part of code in your iframe documents:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
    $(top.document).trigger('keydown',e);
});
```

This should simply "forward" the event to the top document. See http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ and http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ from the jQuery API to be able to play arround it a bit.

Comment: So I tested something like this:
    $('#'+ifID).contents().on('keydown', function(e) {
        console.log(e.which);
        $(top.document).trigger('keydown', e);
    });
It did not however trigger the parent documents keydown for some reason. Also tested $(top).trigger('keydown', e);  I'll investigate further but this should work, so thank you!

Comment: I finally got it to work using:

    `$(top.document).trigger(e);

Before this the issue was that the top parent document wasn't getting the proper event information, but now it does.

Comment: ah good to know, I did not expect to require to trigger the events on the document rather than top... Fixing the answer.